# Searching in a dictionary. Using Regex

Tags: java, regex

How can I use regex for finding a format? I can find a specific word but I want to search for something like this: a?t*(this should be a match to art, attetion - ? means one letter and * n letters but can only be placed at the ending of the word).

So how should I do this?

I don't know how to put this for you to understand. I want to search for a word using a format like w?rd(this suppose to match word, or ward).

What I was looking for was something like this:

```
public boolean regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2Check){

    // You define your regular expression (REGEX) using Pattern

    Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);

    // Creates a Matcher object that searches the String for
    // anything that matches the REGEX

    Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher( str2Check );

    // Cycle through the positive matches and print them to screen
    // Make sure string isn't empty and trim off any whitespace

    while ( regexMatcher.find() ){
        if (regexMatcher.group().length() == str2Check.length()){
            System.out.println( regexMatcher.group().trim() );

            // You can get the starting and ending indexs

            System.out.println( "Start Index: " + regexMatcher.start());
            System.out.println( "Start Index: " + regexMatcher.end());
            return true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    return false;
}
public String regexReplace(String str2Replace){



    Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\\?");

    Matcher regexMatcher = replace.matcher(str2Replace.trim());

    return regexMatcher.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]");

}
public String regexReplace2(String str2Replace){


Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\\*");



Matcher regexMatcher = replace.matcher(str2Replace.trim());


return regexMatcher.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+");}
```

Comment: As stated, your question is not clear enough to be understood.

Comment: `a?t*` matches neither "art" or "attetion", so I recommend you to start by reading the regex syntax guide a bit more carefully.

Comment: Thats what I was asking about. I have a school project what specifically sais to search like that. Can I use regex or not? --- Implement dictionary searching using * (any string, including null, at the end of the word) and ? (one character). 
For example, you can search for a?t*, matching art.

Comment: "?" means 0 or 1 occurance of "previous" character. you will need "a.*?t.*" and a little more knowledge of regex.

Comment: Please don't answer or comment again if you don't understand the question. So apparently I have to implement this myself or use regex as it is as I can't use '?' for one character. The answer to my question should've been something like: No, you can't use regex like that because...

Comment: @Laurentiu - Yes. you can use REGEX if you know how to use it correctly. Period.

Comment: So you want to have some kind of wildcard? It usually makes it easier to understand what you want to have clear examples of input and output. Also, `Please don't comment again if you don't understand the question` isn't how StackOverflow works. Use the comments to clarify your question by editing it, and you'll get answers: the burden of a clear explanation is on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex for strings that start in a and third letter t

```
^a.t
```

Regex for 4 letter words starting with `w` and ending in `rd`

```
^w[a-z]rd$
```